# Moving a sprite along a bezier curve in canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Completely new to canvas and animations. Why won't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2YSt/206/) (Fiddle) work with a sprite but [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2YSt/196/) (Fiddle) works with a rectangle fill?

What am I missing where:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 13, 50);
```

isn't sufficient? It draws it on the canvas, so why won't the object move? I don't need to use `window.requestAnimationFrame` for such a simple task, do I?

Comment: No, sorry, that doesn't appear to have anything to do with images or sprites. My question isn't so much about the bezier curve itself, but how to effectively apply drawImage to it.

Comment: You are always drawing the image on the same position, try `ctx.drawImage(img, point.x, point.y, 13, 50);`.

Comment: Oh wow, duh. It's even in the other Fiddle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not moving it in the first fiddle but redraw it in the same position.

If you change this line:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 13, 50);
```

to:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, point.x-10, point.y-10, 13, 50);
```

it should work. Hope this helps.

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/Z2YSt/207/)**